# Is it much harder to write mobile web apps in Vaadin without TouchKit?

Tags: mobile, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-touchkit

The question says it all. If I don't use TouchKit, which is only free for open source projects, what will be the difficulties I'll likely encounter trying to develop a mobile version of my UI?

I'd go about it via the [UIProvider](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+an+application+with+different+features+for+different+clients) facility.

Many thanks!

Comment: did you hear about responsive framework in Vaadin? in the outside world it is called as RWD.

Comment: The touchkit provides many components optimized for touch interaction and look&feel of the platforms. Without it, you will have to style and make the components more touchfriendly